# How to convert gps receiver native format to google lat long or XY format

Tags: convert, gps, coordinates

I have received some GPS co-ordinates in the following format like - "17267690N 078279340E"..

How to convert the co-ordinates to show it on Google map.

Comment: Can you ask in which projection the coordinates have been delivered? We can try to guess but we may guess wrong. At least you should tell us where in the world that place is for example by sending a link to OpenStreetMap map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the native GPS coordinate system is WGS 84, but one should be wary that the GPS could have been configured to another Lat/long system (wrong datum induce up to 150m error). Looking at your data this is most probably lat/long in decimal degree DDD.DDDDDD for Longitude and DD.DDDDDD for latitude (need to divide both by 10e6). I assume this because you probably have the same precision in Lat and Long, and you don't need three digit for Lat ( -90 to 90) contrary to Long (-180 to 180).

EDIT: However, you should make sure that it is not DD°MM.mmmm by looking at the digits after the degree: if the value never exceed 59.9999, then it was probably DD°MM.mmmm (especially if your point is in the sea, which is not the case here) as suggested by @mkennedy

after, you can convert to Web Mercator (Google maps projection). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/covert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection) for the code and here for a [free converter](http://www.tatukgis.com/Products/CoordinateCalculator/Description.aspx) (Tatukgis)

Comment: Seems obvious indeed. Conversion from command line can be done with cs2cs program. Usage and output with hopefully correct syntax `>cs2cs +init=epsg:4326 +to +init=epsg:3857


078.279340 17.267690


8714016.27      1952008.12 0.00`

Comment: I know the OP accepted the answer but the data could be DD.MMmmmm and DDD.MMmmmm instead. It's just something to watch out for with GPS data.

Comment: @mkennedy you are right, but most of the time you have either decimal degree, either DMS.s. And it is not DMS.s because the 76.9 and 93.4 are not a possible value for seconds. I've edited my post with your warning.

Comment: Thanks! NMEA uses DDMM.mmmm (yet another format!) so I'm always wary with GPS data.

Comment: Something else to point out is that WGS84 may be the *default* setting for most GPS units, but they *can* be set differently or *automatically change* based on the reference map they are displaying. The same can be said of the coordinate format. My Garmin 60CSx supports a wide variety of grids and datums. As @mkennedy said, one should be wary of undocumented GPS data.

Comment: thanks @Chris W for your comment. I said WGS 84 because the OP mentioned "NATIVE" coordinates, but it is true that the GPS could have been configured in another way. I've also edited my post based on your comment. There are indeed several datums used in India, e.g. Indian 1960, Indian 1975, Kalianpur 1880 etc